# Best ways to add security vulnerability checks in spring boot apis

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a problem, I use spring with the multitenant database. I have written rest api and using spring token for validating the user. For all API's we are passing the module id's get/put/delete operations. Here I would like to add a common security check like securityInterceptor. What is the best way to add security checks in spring so that no one can see data of different tenants?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Security annotation @PreAuthorize

You can pass to this annotation logic that checks if client is authorized.

```
@PreAuthorize("localAuthorizationResolver.canAccessData(#pathVariable)
```

LocalAuthorizationResolver is annotated with @Service. In canAccessData method you are able to get security context with informations about user by calling:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```